# How to track the polygon change event?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I need to get the new coordinates of the polygon if the finish button was pressed. I applied pm:update, but this event is not triggered when rotating or moving the polygon. I also tried to use pm:action click, but this event does not give me the opportunity to get the coordinates of the polygon that I was changing.

Answer (score 0):

Listen on the `pm:edit` event, it is fired directly after a change is happend.

```
polygon.on('pm:edit', (e)=>{
   console.log(e);
});
```